# AngularJS $location does not get updated

Tags: angularjs, location, ng-view

I am new to AngularJS and I apologize if this is a stupid question. I am struggling for days now and just can't get my head around it.

I have an application with a main controller and three partials with their own controllers. Everything works fine, except that the $location in the main controller does not change when the user navigates to a view. But the browser always shows the correct URL.

```
sdsApp.controller('mainCtrl', ['$location', function($location) {
    var self = this;
    self.url = $location.absUrl();
}]);
```

However, the controller of the partial will always return the correct current location:

```
sdsApp.controller('homeCtrl', ['$location', function($location) {
    var self = this;
    self.url = $location.absUrl();
}]);
```

[Here is the plunker with the full example](http://plnkr.co/edit/B9VOHX?p=preview)

Comment: I found the solution: the main controller has to listen for the event $locationChangeSuccess and then just read $location.absUrl().

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: the main controller has to listen for the event $locationChangeSuccess and then just read $location.absUrl().

```
myApp.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope','$location', function($scope, $location) {
var self = this;

$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event) {
    self.url = $location.absUrl();
});
```

}]);